# textview center not working

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview set up to display an integer. The range is from 0-255. The textview is right above a seekbar so I want it to always be centered. I tried the gravity center but it did not apply. I also have set the textview to show a custom font so I am not sure if this is affecting the gravity center option. With the current code the textview seems to be left justified.

```
         <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="255"
    android:textSize="37dp"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00" />
```

I display the value

```
     ViewGreen.setText(" " + G_value);
```

Here is the xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarr"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mastersliderback"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:thumb="@drawable/imgsliderred70" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarg"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mastersliderback"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:thumb="@drawable/imgslidergreen70" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarb"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mastersliderback"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:thumb="@drawable/imgsliderblue70" />


<!-- Here is the textView I am editing to make the center apply -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:text="255"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
    android:textSize="38dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="255"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
    android:textSize="38dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="255"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
    android:textSize="38dp" />
```

Screenshot
[image: dimmer]

Final working xml

```
        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewR"
    android:layout_width="73dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="255"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
    android:textSize="37dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity="center"` centers the content inside the `View`.

Use `android:layout_gravity="center"` to center the `View` inside its `parent`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  // or just center, whatever you need
    android:text="255"
    android:textSize="37dp"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF00" />
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity)

Comment: I tried center_horizontal and its still left justified. I also removed the space in the ViewGreen.setText(" " + G_value); between the "".

Comment: Remove your `marginLeft` and see what that does.

Comment: puts the textview to the left side of the window still Justified left. FYI I also removed the font but still not centered.

Comment: Is there a way to set the textview to show a 3 character window ? If I set the window size then the contents may be centered regardless of 1 to 3 characters

Comment: If you are centering the text and the `TextView` then it shouldn't matter...it should stay centered. You can edit your post with the full xml and maybe someone can see what's causing it

Comment: Can you show a picture of what you are expecting? `layout_gravity` is a property of `LinearLayout` so that's why it isn't working. Also `orientation` is a property of `LinearLayout` so that isn't doing you any good. I think there is probably a much easier way to achieve whatever you are trying to accomplish instead of using the `margin` everywhere

Comment: Why don't you use a `LinearLayout` as the root `ViewGroup` with `horizontal orienation` then 3 `LinearLayout`s with `vertical orienation`. Then `layout_gravity` should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Take TextView inside a LinearLayout and give gravity center to that LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes needed by setting the Textview to 3 characters wide. I posted the changes.